# How to play separate audio for different notification responses in iOS using Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, push-notification, avaudioplayer

I have a scenario, I want to play different audios using `AVAudioPlayer` for different notification responses.

for example, when notification response is `yes` I want to play `audio1` and similarly, for `fail`, `audio2`. My code is as below,

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject], fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
//Presenting audioController from here
}
```

`audioController.swift`

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    var player:AVAudioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer()
    if notificationResponse == "yes" {
        audioPath =  NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("audio1", ofType: "mp3")
    } else if notificationResponse == "no" {
        audioPath = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("audio2", ofType: "mp3")
    }
    player = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: NSURL(fileURLWithPath: audioPath!))
    player.numberOfLoops = -1
    player.play()
}
```

The problem is, when both notification arrives at the same time, view controllers are presenting twice and both audios are playing.

How to stop playing the older audio when newer notification is arrived?

Comment: How are you presenting audioController?...You can keep an object of audioController in appdelegate and check if object is not nil before presenting...

Comment: ok. I will try and let you know.

Answer (score 0):

Make `player` var as property for audioController.swift then make your audioController.swift class's object global in AppDelegate then

add a check if audioController.swift class's object is already presented, for that check `presentedViewController` is nil or not nil on which instance you are presenting it, before presenting in `didReceiveRemoteNotification`.

If its already presented then stop player and change player's `audioPath` without presenting audioController again.

```
var audioC : audioController // Its you global var in AppDelegate

//Use this code after adding a check the audioC is already presented or not in didReceiveRemoteNotification
audioC.player.stop() // Stop previous running audio
audioC.player = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: NSURL(fileURLWithPath: newAudioPath!)) // newAudioPath will be your new audio files path
audioC.player.play() // Play the new audio.
```